# Perl module Capture::Tiny capture code in string variable

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the Perl module [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture%3a%3aTiny) to capture evalued Perl code. The problem is the "Print" function returns 1 on success and this returns as a result of the capture if the print is the last statement. How to avoid this. Below is the code.

```
use Capture::Tiny ':all';

my $code = << "PERL_CODE";
    print "Hello world\n";
    #raise_error();
PERL_CODE

my ($merged, @result) = capture_merged {eval $code};

if ($@) {
    $merged  = "Perl code error: $@\n$code\n$merged";
}

print "$merged" . join ("", @result);
```

The output is not as expected:

```
Hello world
1
```

The 1 in the output coming from the Perl "Print" function.

Of course there is an ugly solution is to put "return;" as the last statement in the code fragment but I just do not want it to be like that in case you forgot it.

```
my $code = << "PERL_CODE";
    print "Hello world\n";
    #raise_error();
    return; # this will not return the 1 from the Print function above but ugly.
PERL_CODE
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly? It's doing exactly as it should. If you execute a block of code that has a `print` at the end, the result will always be one. If you have `sub foo { print "hello" }` and call `print foo()` it will also print `hello1`. That is exactly what should happen.

Answer (score 2):

The captured STDOUT is in `$merged`, while the value returned by the code - `1` as you say - is in `@result`.

If you don't want to see the `1` then don't print `@result`.

Do you expect to find something else in there? The value returned by any block of code is rarely printed so you don't normally see it.

Answer (score 0):

1 is coming from `@result`, at the end you are joining the `@result` so you are getting 1.

Try the below

```
if ($@) {
    $merged  = "Perl code error: $@\n$code\n$merged";
}
#print "merged is $merged result is @result";
print "$merged";
```

Comment: Yes the @result holds the return from the evaluated code. You could have `return "your message"` so this gets returned in the @result.

Comment: returning is the only choice you have, don't call it ugly :)